# Including opencv with fetchcontent does not work

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to include opencv in my c++ project. I want CMake to handle this for me.

Currently I'm at the point where I need to include opencv with the tag: `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`

The files in the _deps/opencv-src directory throw the following error though:

```
Scanning dependencies of target VisionC
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/VisionC.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/koen/Vakken/MotionVision/VisionC/main.cpp:2:
/Users/koen/Vakken/MotionVision/VisionC/cmake-build-debug/_deps/opencv-src/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:48:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp' file not found
#include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

It seems Like the files can't include their own headers

My CMakeLists file is still pretty simple:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(VisionC)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
        opencv
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
        GIT_TAG        4.4.0
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(opencv)
if (NOT opencv_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(opencv)
    add_subdirectory(${opencv_SOURCE_DIR} ${opencv_BINARY_DIR})
    include_directories(${opencv_SOURCE_DIR}/include) # "/include" should be deleted somehow...
endif ()

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(opencv)

add_executable(VisionC main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(VisionC opencv_lib)
```

I think the "/include" in the include_directories line hints that the library is included in a directory to "high" or so... I'm not sure how I should change this. If I delete this line I have to include opencv like `#include <include/opencv2/opencv.hpp>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, this is my cmakelists now:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(VisionC)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

# Fetch from git
include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
        opencv
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
        GIT_TAG        4.4.0
)
FetchContent_GetProperties(opencv)
if (NOT opencv_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(opencv)
endif ()
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(opencv)

# Find on pc
set(OpenCV_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

# Link
add_executable(VisionC main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(VisionC ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Comment: Since `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(opencv)` follow the canonical pattern you can remove the `FetchContent_GetProperties`/`FetchContent_Populate` i.e. everything is done by `FetchContent_MakeAvailable`...
ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html#command:fetchcontent_makeavailable

Comment: you're right, I think `include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})` as well

Comment: I tried to do the same as you but I have a list of errors like the following: `Target "opencv_core" INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property contains path:

"~/CLionProjects/vision/cmake-build-debug"

  which is prefixed in the build directory.` Do you know why?

Comment: Honestly, it was for a school project. I just ran with it. I'm sorry. Maybe you could simply  change the value of INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES to exclude that path and see what happens. Honestly if you'd be able to fix that, I think a lot of people would be very happy in the future!

Comment: seems the build is very slow

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by @Typhaon is not a solution at all because it uses find_package alongside FetchContent and only uses the result of the find_package ignoring the fetched content. In, other words if you remove FetchContent usages it will work. If anyone is wondering what is the proper integration of OpenCV with find_package, take a look at the example provided by OpenCV https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/samples/cpp/example_cmake/CMakeLists.txt.

So, what about fetch_content or even using add_subdriectory?
That kind of usage is currently unsupported
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20548

But, I currently found a workaround that works for me with the current release. So the problem is that the targets of the OpenCV modules do not include in them the header include dir so when you are trying to link with them you can but you also need to specify the include directory manually. Currently, there are OPENCV_MODULE_opencv_{module_name}_LOCATION variables that point to the source directory of the module and they can be used for obtaining the include dir. For example

```
target_include_directories(my_target PRIVATE
        ${OPENCV_MODULE_opencv_core_LOCATION}/include
        ${OPENCV_MODULE_opencv_highgui_LOCATION}/include
        )
target_link_libraries(my_target opencv_core opencv_highgui)
```

After this, there is an error like this

```
   52 | #include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And this is because for some reason the opencv_modules.hpp is being generated in the root of the build directory. But fortunately, there is a variable that is pointing to that directory OPENCV_CONFIG_FILE_INCLUDE_DIR. So the final CMake list file looks like the following

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(my_project)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
        opencv
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
        GIT_TAG 4.6.0
        GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(opencv)

add_executable(my_target main.cpp)
target_include_directories(my_target PRIVATE
        ${OPENCV_CONFIG_FILE_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${OPENCV_MODULE_opencv_core_LOCATION}/include
        ${OPENCV_MODULE_opencv_highgui_LOCATION}/include
        )
target_link_libraries(my_target opencv_core opencv_highgui)
```

The downside of this workaround is that the mentioned variables can change over the releases, and this currently works for 4.6.0.