# How can I link opencv to cmake without using find_package?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I hope users could open the software immediately and without installing anything else.

I tried

```
target_link_libraries(main opencv_core490 opencv_highgui490)
```

But the console showed:

```
D:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopencv_core490: No such file or directory
D:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopencv_highgui490: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64156798/including-opencv-with-fetchcontent-does-not-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64156798/including-opencv-with-fetchcontent-does-not-work) is probably what you want then.

Comment: `target_link_libraries(main opencv_core490 opencv_highgui490)` could possibly work if you used `pacman` to install the required dependency.

Comment: Find package is really the easiest and most portable way to link o other libraries. If you use a package manager like vcpkg, find package will just work. There are other solution you can find but it will not be at easy

Comment: Where in your system are the opencv library files? What are their exact filenames?

Comment: I added the opencv related(include, lib, dll) into my project folder. The filename of lib is opencv_world490.lib. The filenames of dll are opencv_world490.dll and opencv_videoio_ffmpeg490_64.dll

Comment: So you have the "world" variant where all rhe modules are combined to a single lib. Try to link opencv_world490.lib. instaad of _core _highgui etc.

Comment: ***I added the opencv related(include, lib, dll) into my project folder.*** Are you sure that the .lib files in that folder are compatible with MinGW and not msvc? If you obtained these from a download and got them from a vc15, vc16 ... folder they are msvc libraries and not compatible with MinGW. Also remember that if you supply the .lib files and .dll files you are going against "I hope users could open the software immediately and without installing anything else." as you are forcing your users to use a specific compiler.

Comment: I understood. The reason was because they are not compatible with MINGW. So what can I do about this or I can only turn into msvc?

Comment: ***So what can I do about this*** Download the proper binaries for your compiler or build them yourself with your compiler. There is no tool to translate the compiled binaries from one compiler to different one.

Comment: Although if your goal is "I hope users could open the software immediately and without installing anything else." you should not ship any binaries in your repository at all because whatever binaries you ship will force your users to use the compiler or OS you choose which may be different from the compiler and OS the user has.  You should do what my first comment said to do.